# Given a finite $p$-group $G$ and $\Phi(G)$ the Frattini subgroup of $G$. Prove $G/\Phi(G)$ is $p$-torsion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, frattini-subgroup

As the title says, I need to prove that every element in $G/\Phi(G)$ has order $p$.  I know by the First Sylow theorem that $G$ contains subgroups of orders $1,p,p^2,\dots,p^{k-1}$ with each normal in the next.

Thus, every maximal subgroup of $G$ has order $p^{k-1}$, so $\Phi(G)$ is the intersection of subgroups of $G$ of order $p^{k-1}$.  However from here I'm stuck.  I do also know that $\Phi(G)$ itself is contained in a maximal subgroup of $G$ (by Sylow), and thus must either be of order $p^{k-1}$ (in which case $G/\Phi(G) \cong \mathcal{C}_p$ and I'm done) or it's properly contained in a maximal subgroup.

I'm unsure of what to do in the latter case.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In finite group theory the Frattini subgroup is usually denoted by $\Phi(G)$. While $F(G)$ often denotes the Fitting subgroup, which is different.

Comment: For your actual question. If $M < G$ is maximal subgroup, show that $M$ is normal in $G$ and $G/M \cong C_p$. From this you can get the result you want.

Comment: The question should be completely in the body of the post, not rely on information in the subject line,

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, I will adhere to this in the future.

Comment: @spin Okay, so since any maximal subgroup $M<G$ has order $p^{k-1}$, $[G:M]=p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, so $M \lhd G$, and thus $G/M \cong \mathcal{C}_p$.  But since $\Phi(G) < H$ for some maximal subgroup $H<G$, we have by the third isomorphism theorem that $(G/\Phi(G))/(H/\Phi(G)) \cong G/H \cong \mathcal{C}_p$?  So $G/\Phi(G)$ contains a subgroup of index $p$ as well?  I'm not sure where to go from here, if I'm given $x\Phi(G) \in G/\Phi(G)$.

Comment: The Frattini subgroup is not contained "in some" maximal subgroup, it is the intersection of all maximal subgroups, so it is contained in *all* of them. The rest of your comment is useless. Instead, remember that if $N$ and $K$ are normal in a group $G$, the $G/(N\cap K)$ embeds into $(G/N)\times(G/K)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay I see.  By embed, you mean that there's an injective mapping from $G/(N \cap K)$ to $G/N \times G/K$?

Comment: @Isochron: Let $x \in G$. The point is that for maximal $M$ we have $G/M \cong C_p$, so $x^p \in M$. So $x^p$ is contained in every maximal subgroup, which is basically what you want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

In finite $p$-groups, $\Phi(G)=G'G^{p}$, where $G^{p}=\langle g^{p}\mid g\in G \rangle$. So for any $g\in G$, $g^{p}$ belongs to $\Phi(G)$. Hence Exp($G/\Phi(G)$)=$p$ and since $G'\le \Phi(G)$, $G/\Phi(G)$ is abelian. We see that $G/\Phi(G)$ is elementary abelian $p$-group.

Comment: $G_p$ usually denotes the $p$-part of $G$, the elements whose order is a power of $p$. The set you describe is usually denoted $G^p$.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I wasn't sure, so I gave the definition too.

Comment: Then... fix it?